# Exception after clicked and closed banner

Tags: android, double-click

I have DoubleClick banners in 'MainActivity'(A) and in 'FindActivity'(B).
When I click banner in A - it opens and I'm pressing 'back' button - A appears again and works fine.
When click banner in B - it opens and I'm pressing 'back' - B did not appears. LogCat says:

```
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.myapp/com.my.myapp.FindActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at com.my.myapp.FindActivity.onCreate(FindActivity.java:125)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-29 16:38:27.542: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  ... 11 more
```

I've put breakpoint at line 125. Surprise - LogCat show exception without reaching breakpoint.
Code in onCreate is:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//line124
m_current = MyApp.sInstance.GetName();//line 125 ========
```

**Update**
sInstance is App singleton.
added correct log copy

**Update2**
Bigger stack trace provided

Comment: 1. what is the exception?? 2. what is sinstance?

Comment: please don't strip stacktraces! Really they are meant to be longer than one line...

Comment: sInstance is null. can I see your singleton?

Comment: sInstance is not null. In fact debuger does not stopping there not on line 125 nor on line 124. For test I have put simple code before line 125 -> int t=0; Same result - null pointer on first lina after super.onCreate. Probably there is problem creating activity again.

Comment: if it is not null, your stacktrace and soruce code are inconsistent

Comment: Can you post the code from your application class where you are setting the sInstance variable?

Comment: blackbelt I made clean and build several timer. then restart whole editor :(

Comment: did you update to adt22?

Comment: blackbelt => Yes. This morning. May be problem is because I'm leaving app when click banner. Probably closing banner Android trying to show my last activity. And because it is not my 'startup' activity - something brokes :(

Comment: ok, open the Android SDK manager and install the Android SDK Build tools. you probably missed to install it .

Comment: Hmm. First 'killed' adb from TaskManager. Probably is not updated correctly and now is not stoping on my breakpoints. Stupid story.

Comment: so you fixed your crash?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30841/discussion-between-kostadin-and-blackbelt)